# Create nested map with new object types from split string

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this stream

```
jedis.lrange("users", 0, -1).stream()
  .map(user -> user.split(":"))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
     user -> user[0], 
     Collectors.toMap(a -> a[1], a2 -> a2[2])
  ));
```

which returns `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` but I want to get `Map<UUID, Map<String, Long>>` Index 0 should be convert to UUID, 1 to String, 2 to Long. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider trying to parse the Strings you want to convert? Something in the lines of the following:

```
Map<UUID, Map<String, Long>> groupedNestedMap = jedis.lrange("users", 0, -1)
        .stream()
        .map(user -> user.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(user -> UUID.fromString(user[0]), 
                Collectors.toMap(a -> a[1], a2 -> Long.parseLong(a2[2]))));
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I have error ```Array type expected; found 'java.lang.Object'```

Comment: ```user[0], a[1], a2[2]```

Comment: Ok I think the problem here is that `lrange()` returns a `List<String>` and I was assuming it's a `String`. Check the updated answer please.

Comment: Now error ```Cannot resolve method 'stream()'``` in ```users.stream``` and ```Cannot resolve method 'split(java.lang.String)'``` in ```user.split```

Comment: Ok could you please confirm the return type of `lrange()` please as otherwise this is going to be difficult for us to follow?

Comment: java.util.List<String>

Comment: Ok so previous code should have worked.. is the updated answer any different?

Comment: Still error ```Array type expected; found 'java.lang.Object'``` with ```user[0], a[1], a2[2]```

Comment: @Dr.Bright *Array type expected*... indicates that the type you're trying to infer just might be wrong. See the edit in the answer to use the result type as specified.